# trouble understanding the behavior of str() in mypy with --py2 flag

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-analysis, typechecking, mypy

I have a piece of code

```
1. b = u'\xe6' #type: unicode
2. c = str(b) #type: str
3. d = c #type: str
```

I run this with the python 2 flag in mypy.

My expectation is that there should be an error at line 2. str(b) returns a type **unicode** and c has an expected type of **str** therefore there should be a type incompatibility issue. But no errors thrown.

On the other hand if I explicitly do

```
1. b = u'\xe6' #type: unicode
2. c = str(b) #type: unicode
3. d = c #type: str
```

Then there is an error at line 3, stating cannot assign unicode to str, which is somewhat expected.

So the issue is in my understanding of str(), shouldn't str() return the same type as its input? or does it implicitly cast everything to str, if yes then shouldn't there be an error at line 2 instead of line 3 in the second example.

From the current behavior, str() adopts the type of the variable that it is being assigned to.

Comment: "shouldn't str() return the same type as its input" - you appear to have severely misunderstood what `str` means.

Comment: hence the need to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` returns an object of type `str`. Under rare and unusual circumstances, it may return an instance of a subclass of `str`, but it definitely doesn't return an object of whatever type you passed in.

Line 2 passes type checking in snippet 2 because mypy has a [specific special case](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/duck_type_compatibility.html) that says `str` is compatible with `unicode` on Python 2, but not vice versa.

Comment: got it. what would be the rare or unusual circumstances that str returns a subclass.

Comment: @fazkan: Something with a `__str__` method that returns a `str` subclass instance.

Comment: I thought unicode behaved the same way. thanks for the answer.